# FlatList - loops items when fetching more with no items left - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching data from the api and fetch more data every 15 items. However, when there is no more data left, it's still trying to fetch more and gives an error that next item doesn't exist or just loops the items from 0. How can I stop fetching the data on the last item from the database? Here is my code:

```
export default class One extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchMore = this._fetchMore.bind(this);
    this.fetchData = this._fetchData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isLoadingMore: false,
      _data: null,
      _dataAfter: '',
      accessToken: "",
    };
  }
async componentWillMount() {
try {
      let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN).then(JSON.parse);
      if(!accessToken) {
          this.redirect('login');

      } else {
        this.setState({accessToken: accessToken})

      }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
        this.redirect('login');
    }  

     this.fetchData(responseJson => {
      const data = responseJson;
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        _data: data,
        _dataAfter: responseJson.after,
      });
    });
}    
  _fetchData(callback) {
      const params = this.state._dataAfter !== ''
      ? `&after=${this.state._dataAfter}`
      : '';
    fetch(`https://mywebsite.com/posts?limit=15${params}`,
         {
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.state.accessToken.token,
         }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(callback)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
 _fetchMore() {
    this.fetchData(responseJson => {
      const data = this.state._data.concat(responseJson);
      this.setState({
        isLoadingMore: false,
        _data: data,
        _dataAfter: responseJson.after,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (  
        <FlatList
        numColumns={1}
          data={this.state._data}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
                <View>
                <Text>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
           </View>  
            );
          }}
         onEndReached={() =>
            this.setState({ isLoadingMore: true }, () => this.fetchMore())}
          ListFooterComponent={() => {
            return (
              this.state.isLoadingMore &&
              <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="small" />
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      );
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make params for notice that no items left

Change state to

```
this.state = {
  isLastData: false, // this new var
  isLoading: true,
  isLoadingMore: false,
  _data: null,
  _dataAfter: '',
  accessToken: "",
};
```

Make fetch more like this

```
_fetchMore() {
    this.fetchData(responseJson => {
      const data = this.state._data.concat(responseJson.children);
      this.setState({
        isLastData: data.length > 0 ? false : true, 
        isLoadingMore: false,
        _data: data,
        _dataAfter: responseJson.after,
      });
    });
  }
```

Add logic to onEndReached

```
            onEndReached={
            () => {
                if (! this.state.isLastData) {
                    this.setState({ isLoadingMore: true }, () => this.fetchMore())
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This line gives me an error: ```if (!this.state.isLastData)```

Comment: did you add isLastData to your state? can you change server data response ? if not i will update code for you

Comment: I did add it to my state. Unfortunately, I can't change server data response.

Comment: I am not sure how to check the last item

Comment: what the last data response ? is response children empty?

Comment: I updated the answer, if response children empty, it will not loaded again

Comment: ```if (!this.state.isLastData)``` still gives a SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Comment: owh sorry, curve is lost

Comment: When I go to the end of the list, it gives an error "No item for index 20", and I noticed that my items doesn't load by 15, but load all together. Is that something else wrong with my code?

Comment: is paging params for request to server is correct ?

Comment: I believe so, and data in db from this request looks like this: ```    {
        "id": 2,
        “name”: “xxx”,
        “description ”: “xxx”  
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
        “name”: “xxx”,
        “description ”: “xxx”
    },
…```

Comment: can you give me screenshot of "No item for index 20" message ?

Comment: Can you give me screenshot of response data?

Comment: hmm i have no idea about this error "No item for index 20"

Comment: am I doing something wrong that it displays all the data at once no matter that I say limit=15? or I need to set it up somehow differently to specify the number of items I want to get?

Comment: Just try logging data when error and check console log, did your code already updated and already more different than post on this thread?

Comment: In  _fetchMore() I realized that I don't have children so I got rid of it, but now when I have  ```const data = this.state._data.concat(responseJson);``` the data loads in a loop and besides that all data loads in once. Limit as I said doesn't work at all. The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: i think problem occured there at "the data loads in a loop"